# Accessing a controller from a external library file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have added a external library controller in "**application/libraries/Validate_login.php**".

When i load a controller in **application/controllers/** from external library controller, i'm getting error `Library verifylogin Not Found.`

Validate_login.php

```
class Validate_login extends CI_Controller {
      function __construct()
       {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('loginuser');
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->library('verifylogin');// controller which is in application/controllers/
       } }
```

Comment: i'm loading library `verifylogin` in the file `Validate_login`. Please under stand the question @karanthakkar.

Comment: @crazy developer... karan thakkar is right. please understand codeigniter your saying you named you library "Validate_login.php" ... application/libraries/Validate_login.php so try this $this->load->library('Validate_login');

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper `library` and `controller` are two different things.
you write a library save it `application/libraries/` is correct but library extending a controller !!! and `When i load a controller in application/controllers/ from external library controller` you don't need to load controller. basically you are puzzled.
put `controller extends CI_Controller` in `application/controllers/` and library in `application/libraries/` load library in controller **OR** auto load it in autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('verifylogin');// controller which is in application/controllers/
```

*$this->load->library()* will load libraries within the "application/libraries" directory. That's why it cannot be found.

Comment: then how to load the controller file? using the PHP method `require_once();` "

Comment: you don't need to load `controllers` @CrazyDeveloper read my comment above.

Comment: Why are you trying to load a controller file? It can't be done.